# Memory behavior of recursivity using Lambda

Tags: c#, memory, lambda, closures

I'm doing a preorder traversal of a binary tree using the following code:

```
        public void PreorderTraversal(Action<BinaryTreeNode<T>> act) {
            Action<BinaryTreeNode<T>> InnerTraverse = null;
            InnerTraverse = (node) => {
                if (node == null) return;
                act(node);
                InnerTraverse(node.Left);
                InnerTraverse(node.Right);
            };
            InnerTraverse(this.Root);
        }
```

Is this approach of using a locally defined lambda to recurs over the tree worse from a performance perspective in relation to simply defining the InnerTraverse function as a method on the BinaryTree class, which is where the PreorderTraversal function itself is defined?

Comment: "Duplicated" how? Any closure capturing variables results in a new instance of the hidden closure class. This is true for each call of a method, and even for closures found inside the statement block of a loop. What kind of duplication are you concerned about? Did you look at the compiled IL, e.g. via ildasm.exe, to understand better what's happening in the compiled code? What research _have_ you done? I don't understand what you would consider "responsible" and "naïve". Please improve the clarity of your question.

Comment: @PeterDuniho Essentially, I'm wondering if using a lambda in this manner is naive in relation to simply defining two functions at the class level.  I'll reword the question.  I can measure the performance, but I'm not clear on the implications of using a lambda vs. a class method.

Comment: Certainly, there's no need to use lambda expressions, or any kind of delegate, to do a proper traversal of a binary tree. So if that's your primary question, then yes...the code you posted is the wrong way to do it. One should always choose the simpler implementation when possible. The specifics may vary according to your binary tree data structure; you should include a good [mcve] if you want specific help with a traversal implementation.

Comment: @PeterDuniho I was exploring this approach to further encapsulate the traversal code (rather than having a private method on the BinaryTree class [in fact, three, since there's Inorder and Postorder]).  Ultimately, I will write a non-recursive function to accomplish this.  This genesis of this question was simply to understand the implications of using a lambda recursively, which isn't something I've done before.

Comment: Well, the `PreorderTraversal()` method is (presumably) called only once, so at least you're not creating `InnerTraverse` multiple times. But you don't need the delegate at all, just to abstract the `act` delegate used for each node. And in other scenarios, where you might want to abstract how the left and right nodes are retrieved, that can be done by delegates passed to the traversal method as well. Based on the information you've provided so far, I see no need to wrap the method's code in another method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The sample method will be translated by the compiler to something like this:

```
class Closure
{
     public Action<BinaryTreeNode<T>> act;
     public Action<BinaryTreeNode<T>> InnerTraverse;

     public void InnerTraverseFunc(BinaryTreeNode<T> node)
     {
         if (node == null) return;
         this.act(node);
         this.InnerTraverse(node.Left);
         this.InnerTraverse(node.Right);
     }
}

public void PreorderTraversal(Action<BinaryTreeNode<T>> act)
{
    var c = new Closure();
    c.act = act;
    c.InnerTraverse = new Action<BinaryTreeNode<T>>(c.InnerTraverseFunc);
    c.InnerTraverse(this.Root);
}
```

As you can see, the cost is one new type per `T`, 2 heap allocations per each root method call plus using delegate calls vs direct calls with regular static recursive method.

IMO the additional runtime cost is not so big, but at the same time since there is absolutely no benefit of using recursive lambda in such scenarios, better off to be avoided.